# Keeping web application state in AJAX applications

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

What ways are there for keeping the application state between requests? Client managed cookies, descriptive URLs, what else?

Please make sure that by clients I mean thick JavaScript clients. The server side is just a bunch of JSON service, nothing else. All rendering is done on the client.

Comment: Could you offer a little more detail? It's difficult to make suggestions when the question is so vague. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have an JSON service to get and set session data.